# SQL Profiler displaying stored procedure that doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, stack-trace, sql-server-profiler

I have an automated service that runs 3 stored procedure namely sp_1, sp_2, sp_3. When I was running SQL Trace, it displayed the following results

```
EXEC sp_1
EXEC sp_1
EXEC sp_2
EXEC sp_2
EXEC sp_4
EXEC sp_4
EXEC sp_2
EXEC sp_2
```

I don't know where the sp_4 came from. It doesn't exist in my automated service nor database.

Comment: Check the other columns in the trace like host name, application name, and process id to identify the source of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it sounds snippy, but who cares what is in the dababase?

The profiler shows what SQL gets executed. I can call in "EXEC funnybunny" and SQL Server will throw an error - AND the profiler will show that as being called.

So, in your case - stop looking at the database. Rather go to the application and look there why you call a SP that does not exist in the database. Look at the applicaiton layer (and the trace in more detail should tell you the call fails).

Comment: you're right, the app had a different kind of problem when I debugged. thank you!